# number of people that has visited the website

Tags: web, analytics

I am working on a website i will like to know the number of people who has visited the website. Can someone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use google analytics: http://www.google.com/analytics/

Answer (score 3):

I would give you a code to insert but to be honest the best option is to use something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/). It gives you a very good analysis of your website visits and has many features that will take you a very long time to develop

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this with asp.net, I presume you're running on IIS.  Make sure logging is enabled for the site you're working with and then you can determine from the log files how many users are coming to your site by IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Since it wasn't yet mentioned here in years, let me add that [**AWStats**](https://awstats.sourceforge.io/) is very different from **Google Analytics**, but may anyway be a good [*web server traffic analysis tool for network administrators*](http://www.cardinalpath.com/dont-even-think-of-comparing-awstats-to-google-analytics/).